# How to remove admob blank ads in react native application?

Tags: admob, react-native, react-native-ios

I have create one application using **React native** Framework and Monetize with **Admob** ads but there some issue my *internet are off* there some show in **blank white space** in my application. how to solve this issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I do this by buffering them and testing the size. "usually", if the size is 0 the file is.... have a look at https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onerror

Comment: if you are using react-native-admob library, you can use the onAdFailedToLoad prop which will be called if the ad couldn't loaded

Answer (score 0):

If network unavailability is the only case, you can put adView in condition while rendering.

```
{netAvailable ? renderAdView() : null}
```

You can check [NetInfo](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) for network state

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the container-view before the ad is `loaded`

```
const MyAdmobBannerAd = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ height: loaded ? 'auto' : 0 }}>
      <AdMobBanner
        /** adSize, and adUnit */
        onAdLoaded={() => setLoaded(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```